# How to detect collision between two sprites

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

I have two sprites:one character sprite and another one is obstacle sprite. obstacle sprite is child of another sprite called bgSprite which is continuously moving. How can i detect collision between them. Please help me. Thanks in advance
Here is some code:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"BoyRunAnimation.plist"];

CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"BoyRunAnimation.png"];
[self addChild:spriteSheet];        

self._character = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Boy_Run_0003.png"];
self._character.position = ccp(80, 150);
[spriteSheet addChild:self._character];
[self boyRunningAnimation];
```

//obstacles

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    int xPos=500+500*i;
    if (xPos<2*_roadImage1.contentSize.width)
    {
        CCSprite *obstacle=[CCSprite node];
        obstacle.textureRect=CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, _roadImage1.contentSize.height);
        obstacle.color=ccc3(255, 255,255);

        if (xPos <= _roadImage1.contentSize.width)
        {
            obstacle.position=ccp(xPos, _roadImage1.contentSize.height/2);

            [_roadImage1 addChild:obstacle z:0 tag:1];
        }
        else
        {
            obstacle.position=ccp(xPos-_roadImage1.contentSize.width, 60);

            [_roadImage2 addChild:obstacle z:0 tag:2];
        }
        [obstacleArray addObject:obstacle];
    }    
}
```

and in the update:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(self._character.boundingBox, obstacle.boundingBox))
{
    isTouchActive=NO;

    NSLog(@"collision");
}
```

Comment: use CGRectIntersectRect([characterSprite textrureRect],[obstacleSprite textureRect]);

Comment: it is not working on proper position

Comment: can you add some code to your question?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873199/how-to-detect-collision-of-sprite-in-cocos2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the parents. _character's parent and obstacle's parent isn't the same CCNode, so their positions don't have common space. You need to translate positions of one boundingBox to another space.

edit:

```
 CCRect obstacleBox = [obstacle boundingBox];
 CCPoint obstaclePosition = obstacleBox.origin;
 obstaclePosition = [[obstacle parent] convertToWorldSpace:obstaclePosition];
 obstaclePosition = [[self._character parent] convertToNodeSpace:obstaclePosition];
 obstacleBox.origin = obstaclePosition;
 if (CGRectIntersectsRect(self._character.boundingBox, obstacleBox))
    {
        isTouchActive=NO;
        NSLog(@"collision");
    }
```

Comment: Try now, I make mistake in one line.

Comment: collision detected but not on the perfect position. detected after some distance

Comment: I made more mistakes when I write this. Try now :P

Comment: hey its working but not look like realistic collision i think that bcoz of cgrectintersect. how can i detect collsion realistic in my case. plz help me for that

Comment: This isn't a perfect colision detection. If you want something more precise, you should use physics engine like Box2d or read this topic http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-using-color-blending/